# Continuous injection $S^1\to S^1$.

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, complex-analysis

I have been told that a continuous injection $S^n \to S^n$ is automatically a homeomorphism.

However, the mapping $S^1\to S^1: e^{it}\mapsto e^{it/2}$ where $0 \le t < 2\pi$ is injective. So, it cannot be continuous?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That map is discontinuous at $1$. In fact, if $f$ is your map, then $\lim_{n\to\infty}e^{2\pi in/(n+1)}=1$, but\begin{align}\lim_{n\to\infty}f\left(e^{2\pi in/(n+1)}\right)&=\lim_{n\to\infty}e^{\pi in/(n+1)}\\&=e^{\pi i}\\&=-1\\&\ne f(1).\end{align}

Comment: Thanks for your answer!

Comment: I've deleted my first sentence and added that proof.

Answer (score 1):

You're correct.

If you think of $S^1$ as a quotient of $[0, 2\pi)$ then it's well defined, but is not continuous, since $\approx 2\pi \mapsto \approx -1$ even though $\approx 2\pi \sim 0$ should get sent to $\approx 1$ by continuity.

Can you make this argument precise?

---

I hope this helps ^_^

Comment: Thanks for your answer!

Comment: I don't think "quotient" is quite the right word above.

Comment: @RobArthan -- hm... I guess you're right. Do you have a better word?

Comment: "Continuous image"?